# Display only required radio buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having set of radio buttons for which I want to display the radio buttons based on value selected in select tag. Its working partly. If I select 2014, it should display first radio button, if I select 2013 it should display two radio buttons.

Currently if I select 2014, it shows first radio button, then select 2013  it displays two radio buttons, if I select back 2014, it still displays two radio buttons(Only first radio button should display)

Here is my code

```
$('.ncbclaim-slider').addClass('dontshow');    
    $('#eForm_registeredDate').change(function() {    
        $('.ncbclaim-slider').removeClass('dontshow');    
        var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
        var registeredYear = parseInt($(this).val());   
        $('.ncbclaim-slider .radio-box').show();            
        if($(this).val() != '0') {            
            var noNcbYear =  currentYear - registeredYear;            
            $('input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimInLastPolicyPeriod"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parent().parent().hide();                        
        } else {
            $('.ncbclaim-slider').addClass('dontshow');
        }
 });
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/38/

Please let me know whether I should add anything to my code?

Comment: You don't need to do parseInt for the result of 'getFullYear'. It is the number type from the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding the radio buttons, but not showing it.
On page load, all radio button are shown by default.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/40/)

jQuery

```
$('.ncbclaim-slider').addClass('dontshow');    

$('#eForm_registeredDate').change(function() {              
    if($(this).val() != '0') {   
        var noNcbYear =  new Date().getFullYear() - $(this).val();   
        $('.ncbclaim-slider .radio-box').show();                         
        $('.ncbclaim-slider').removeClass('dontshow');      
        $('input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimInLastPolicyPeriod"]').parent().parent().show();  

        $('input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimInLastPolicyPeriod"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parent().parent().hide();                        
    } else {
        $('.ncbclaim-slider').addClass('dontshow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Can it be optimized? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can in many ways. I would start with renaming your class to a smaller one.

Comment: But, I want in terms of coding.. I shouldn't change the classes names. because its already fixed

Comment: Your code seems fine. If you still want to optimize, I have made a small change to code, so that, it first checks the drop down selected value.

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider accepting the answer and/or giving an up vote.

Comment: Accepted rohith. I don't see any other changes ?